# IDE versus SCSI Disk When Running Cloudera Hadoop VMWare CDH 4.2.0

Tags: hadoop, vmware

I [downloaded](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera%27s+Hadoop+Demo+VM+for+CDH4) the Cloudera CDH 4.2.0 Hadoop image and tried to run it on the latest VMWare player for Windows 7 64-bit.  My hard drives are both SSDs.

When I did I saw the following pop-up.  Can someone interpret this for me and recommend a course of action?  I'm not sure if I should be concerned or not.

[image]

Comment: Is there a Stack Exchange that would be better suited?  Please advise.  Looks like it'll be closed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your phzsical drives, but rather the virtual disk files. AFAIK there is some kind of converting utility for these situations...